# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected reshape_1_input to have shape (None, 70, 280) but got array with shape (70, 280)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, dimension, sequential

I'm learning keras and trying to run my own model myself.
input data is image, output data is steering data
Problem is that Input_shape has something wrong I think.
I tried some ways people suggested

1. np.expand_dims
2. model.summary()

But I can't fix error... 
I think I almost fix it but I don't know how to add first dimension (None,...)
would you help me? plz... thanks for reading

here is my code

```python
#Import Keras and ...
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.core import Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import time


#Parameters
NB_EPOCH=20
BATCH_SIZE=100
VERBOSE=1
OPTIMIZER=Adam()
VALIDATION_SPLIT=0.2
IMG_ROWS,IMG_COLS=280, 70
INPUT_SHAPE=(1,IMG_ROWS, IMG_COLS)

#Path
image_path = 'C:/Users\JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras/Train_data_img/'
text_path = 'C:/Users\JUNG HYEONG SEOK/Keras/Train_data_txt/'
img_list=os.listdir(image_path)


#Define function
def read_label() : # Read the whole training labels

    Text_steering = open("%sSteering_Data.txt" % text_path, 'r')

    Steering_label = Text_steering.read().splitlines()

    return Steering_label

def read_images(img_list) : # Read the training images by batch size

    images = []

    for name in img_list:

        img = Image.open('%s%s'%(image_path, name))
        img_arr=np.array(img)
        img_dims=np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis=1)
        images.append(img_dims)

    return images


#Model
model = Sequential()
input_shape=(70,280)
model.add(Reshape(input_shape+(1,), input_shape=input_shape))

#1st layer
model.add(Conv2D(24, kernel_size=5, padding="same",data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#2nd layer
model.add(Conv2D(36, kernel_size=5, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#3rd layer
model.add(Conv2D(48, kernel_size=5, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#4th layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#5th layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

#Output layer
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()


#Train Data
print("Now I'm reading training data")
x_train=read_images(img_list)
y_train=read_label()

#Compile

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=OPTIMIZER)

#Fit
NB_FILES=18900
for i in range(NB_FILES-1):
    history=model.fit(x_train[i],y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,epochs=NB_EPOCH,
                  verbose=VERBOSE,validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the reshape layer at the beginning of your network?

Comment: I tried to this example in https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape

Comment: Yes but that doesn't say what is the purpose, you shouldn't blindly follow examples or tutorials.

Comment: my purpose is that fulfilling four dimension as keras want